# What does response time mean in Azure?

Tags: azure, http, server

I'm running an HTTP server in Microsoft Azure.

It sometimes show response times (for HTTP requests) of greater than 30mins.

Which of the following is displayed as the response time in Azure?

Time between,

1. the arrival of the request to server and time at which the first byte of the server was sent from server
2. arrival of the request and the emission of last byte in respone from the server

In case 2 ,  can the high response time due to the slow internet connections of my clients?